# ROXML XML MAPPING Text Node Value

Tags: ruby

I have a simple XML Format Definition 
`<list>
   <tag postion="11" length="12">VALUE_NODE</tag>
     <other tag1,tag2 nodes...>
</list>`

And i have the following classes:

```
Class List
 include ROXML 
 xml_accessor :tags, :as => [Tag] 
end

class Tag
 include ROXML

 xml_accessor :position, :from => "@position"
 xml_accessor :length, :from => "@length"
 end

 tag1 = Tag.new
 tag1.position = "2"
 tag1.length = "23"
 tag2 = Tag.new
 tag2.position = "2"
 tag2.length = "23"

 tag_list = TagList.new
 tag_list.tags = [tag1,tag2]
```

OK I can set all Properties with the setter/getter Methods and serialize the object but how i can set the value_node?? Like 
I searched through many pages but without success.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know this gem but on github's project I read https://github.com/Empact/roxml/blob/master/README.rdoc:

```
xml_reader :value, :from => :content
```

so for you have to had :

```
  class Tag
    include ROXML

    xml_accessor :position, :from => "@position"
    xml_accessor :length, :from => "@length"
    xml_accessor :my_node, :from => :content
  end

  tag1 = Tag.new
  tag1.position = "2"
  tag1.length = "23"
  tag1.my_node = "my Node value"

  tag_list = TagList.new
  tag_list.tags = [tag1]
```

So

```
p tag_list.to_xml.to_s
```

Gives

```
<taglist>
  <tag position="2" length="23">my Node value</tag>
</taglist>
```